# Removing \u0152 unicode python

Tags: python, regex, string

For the life of me i can't remove \u0152.

Using python 2

WHen I attempt to do str(table), i get: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0152' in position 473: ordinal not in range(128)

I've tried table.replace('\u0152', '') as well as regex.

```
table = \n2002 \u0152 present Assistant Professor, Department of Development Sociology,    Cornell \n   University, Ithaca, NY   \n \n1999 \u0152
```

Comment: Which exact Python are you using? Also, I assume you have quotes around the `table` assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the UnicodeEncodeError when doing `str(table)`, you could use `table.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`.  This removes all characters that can’t be encoded to ASCII, which may be unwanted depending on your data.

`replace` may also work if you make sure that both `table` and the arguments are unicode strings, e.g. `table.replace(u'\0152', u'')`.

Answer (score 0):

The string value `table` is **not modified in-place** by the call to `replace()`. The replaced version is returned instead. You will need to re-assign if you want to modify the variable `table`.

```
table = '\n2002 \u0152 present Assistant Professor, Department of Development Sociology,    Cornell \n   University, Ithaca, NY   \n \n1999 \u0152'
table = table.replace('\u0152', '')
print table # Should have the output you want.
```

Comment: When you print repr(output) you still get '\u0152' This is important to me because I am attempting to use regex to parse this text document.

Comment: @user3314418, I tried that and it is still gone. Are you sure that you still get it for *this exact example?*